# Is it acceptable to use ( a xor b) as an input to a kmap?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

So I Have a state diagram that uses (a xor b) as the transition expression.  I can convert this the 2 inputs and create a state transition table, but is it acceptable to use the expression (a xor b) as is?  And therefore follow through with kmaps using this.... and finally a logic circuit using  this xor and a not gate to achieve the 2 two states?  Or is it necessary to break it into the individual inputs and resolve that way?

Comment: There is no law against using xor that I am aware of.  Freedom of speech and all that.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you do with the expression ... but presumably you'd physically implement it using some circuitry. And depending on the physical nature of that implementation, certain logic gates will be preferred over others.  And finally, for some reason XOR's don't seem to come very naturally in the physical world.